# MPI dynamic array using malloc

Tags: c, arrays

I am having problem while creating dynamic array using both malloc and calloc.

```
    int main() {
      float *xd_real_send;
      int Nooflines_Real;
      int *X;
      float test[500];

      Nooflines_Real = count_lines(infile);
      printf("Nooflines_Real: %d\n", Nooflines_Real);

      X = (int *) malloc(Nooflines_Real*sizeof(int));
      xd_real_send = (float *) calloc (Nooflines_Real,sizeof(float));

      printf("size of X %d, test %d and size of xd_real_send %d\n",
      sizeof(X)/sizeof(int),sizeof(test)/sizeof(float),
      sizeof(xd_real_send)/sizeof(float));fflush(stdout);

    }
```

And the output is

```
    Nooflines_Real: 40
    size of X 2, test 500 and size of xd_real_send 2
```

Could you please tell what Am I doing wrong.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: `sizeof(X)` is the `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576 @dreamcrash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` and `xd_real_send` are defined as pointers.

The `sizeof` operator applied returns the amount of memory use by the pointer, not the size of what the pointer refers to.

It not possible (in any portable way) to request the size of a memory block once allocated dynamically and refered by some pointer.

For dynamically allocated memory the application needs to take care of keeping track of how large those memory blocks are.

---

`test` is defined expliciltly as an array, so `sizeof` is able to determine the array's size.

Comment: Could you please tell how can i check if array of size 40 is created for xd_real_send.

Comment: Test `((Nooflines_Real == 40) && (NULL != (xd_real_send  = calloc(Nooflines_Real, sizeof(float))))` @user1733911

Comment: if((Nooflines_Real == 40) && (NULL != (xd_real_send = calloc(Nooflines_Real, sizeof(float))))){
     printf("ok");
  } else {
     printf("not ok");
  }

output was  "not ok"